# Spring Batch: Child step depends on multiple parent steps

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring Batch we can create one step which is dependent on other like:

```
<batch:job id="firstJob">
        <batch:step id="firstStep" next="secondStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="firstTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="secondStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="secondTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

In my case, we have dependency as shown below, task C (child) needs to be executed only when A (parent) and B (parent) both are completed:

[image]

Is there any way in Spring Batch where we can say something like:

```
<batch:job id="firstJob">
        <batch:step id="A,B" next="C">
            <batch:tasklet ref="firstTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
        ...
</batch:job>
```

What I thought of is using listener on A and B, and keep track of both listeners in database. When both listeners gets executed, task C can be invoked.

Please help.

**Note**: I am using Spring Batch version: 2.1.9-RELEASE, if above requirement is available on higher releases, I can update version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"next"` tag as many times as you want to define a chain so:

```
<batch:step id="A" next="B">
  <batch:tasklet ref="firstTasklet"/>
</batch:step>
<batch:step id="B" next="C">
  <batch:tasklet ref="secondTasklet"/>
</batch:step>
<batch:step id="C">
  <batch:tasklet ref="thirdTasklet"/>
</batch:step>
```

The chain is: A -> B -> C
C step will be executed after B

Comment: Luca, thanks, but A and B steps are independent. Both of them are going to run in parallel and can finish at different times.

Comment: If A and B are independent I think you have to split flow as described in [5.3.5 - Split flow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful anymore but:

```
<job id="job1">
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="stepC">
        <flow>
            <step id="stepA" parent="stepA" />
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="stepB" parent="stepB"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="stepC" parent="stepC"/>
</job>
```

So C will execute once A and B have executed.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps

Comment: I see this is just an example of the split flow Luca suggested.